# How do you apply Boundary Conditions when using Discrete Fourier Transforms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem

Let's say I have a very simple steady-state BVP with Dirichlet BCs:

$$u_{xx} = 2, \ x\in [0,1]; u(x_{i=0}) = 0, u(x_{i=N-1}) = 1$$

If I take the Fourier Transform of the 2nd order finite difference equation, I obtain:

$$\mathcal{F}\big(\frac{u(x_{i+1})+u(x_{i-1})-2u(x_i)}{h^2} = 2\big) \rightarrow \frac{(1-e^{-jk})(e^{jk}-1)}{h^2}\hat{u} = 2 \rightarrow^{divide} \boxed{\hat{u} = 2\frac{h^2}{(1-e^{-jk})(e^{jk}-1)}}$$

I know I can't just inverse Fourier Transform to get the answer because I'd get division by 0 at the boundaries. So, what are the steps for applying the BCs?

Comment: @Gonçalo I'm trying to use the Fourier Transform to obtain the particular solution rather than use traditional methods. However this method results in division by 0 so I need to find out how to apply BCs to avoid this issue. Look at the boxed equation, at k = 0 and $2\pi$ we get 0 in the denominator.

Comment: Hint: What do your equations look like at the nodes right next to the boundaries? Does the Dirichlet boundary condition let you simplify them at all? Are you sure they have the same form as the other equations in the interior nodes?

Comment: @whpowell96 Well assuming that beyond the nodes (which I forgot to define), we have $u_{x<0} = 0,u_(x>1) = 0$ we would have at the nodes right next to the boundary: $u(x_{i=1})_{xx} = \frac{u(x_2) + u(x_0) - 2 u(x_1)}{h^2} = \frac{u(x_2) + 0 - 2 u(x_1)}{h^2}$ and $u(x_{i=N-2})_{xx} = \frac{u(x_{N-1}) + u(x_{N-3}) - 2 u(x_{N-2})}{h^2} = \frac{1 + u(x_{N-3}) - 2 u(x_{N-2})}{h^2}$. And as for how that might simplify, let me go ahead and see if I can't work it out on my whiteboard.

Comment: You already know $u(x_0) = u(0)$ and $u(x_N) = u(1)$ so those can go to the RHS

Comment: @whpowell96 I should have said f(x) instead of u_{xx} since they're interchangeable. That in mind, so I would have $f(x_1)h^2 - u(0) = u(x_2) - 2u(x_1)$ and $f(x_{N-2})h^2 - u(1)=u(x_{N-3}) - 2u(x_{N-1})$ for the RHS ($f(x,y)$) at the nodes right next to the boundaries. Does that look right?

Comment: You should get a different equation (only two unknowns) at these boundaries which changes their Fourier transform. You look like you've got it just make sure your indices on the right boundary are correct

Comment: The indices should be correct since there are N-1 points, so at i = N-2, we should have x right next to the boundary unless I'm mistaken. I took the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ right next to the Boundaries and I got $\hat{f}(k_{1})h^2 - 0 = (e^{jk}-2)\hat{u}(k_{1})$ and $\hat{f}(k_{N-2})h^2 =1 + (e^{-jk}-2)\hat{u}(k_{N-2})$. at k = 0 I would have $\hat{f}(0) = -\hat{u}$ and at $k_{N-2}$, due to the periodic property, I'm assuming I'd get the same for whatever k is + the BC.

Comment: @whpowell96 So would I just not have info fight at the boundary, i.e. at i = 0 and i = N-1? Like information would be lost at those points similar to how we lose a point when we take a finite derivative? Or is this fine?